# How to migrate a Windows Server 2003 physical server to Xen VM

Tags: windows, xen, physical-to-virtual

We have some 10 physical servers running Windows Server 2003. Now we have bought a new xen server.

I have added Windows Server 2008 R2 as host as a guest VM in xen host.  Now we are planning to move the physical boxes to xen as VM. I Googled it and could see most people suggested using a P2V tool, but I am not aware of one.

Any clear ideas or steps to do the above mentioned will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your second sentence makes no sense at all, secondly a 5 second google search for 'xen p2v' links to lots of ways to do this, including [THIS](http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/tip/Citrix-XenServer-tip-Doing-a-physical-to-virtual-conversion) one. Try to put/some effort into things next time before coming on here, it is a site for professional sysadmins after all.

Comment: The linked answer provides only a way to do a Linux P2V migration, while the question specifically asks about Windows.